# 2 ways to use Json_array_elements_text() in PostrgeSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

Here are two ways to use `json_array_elements_text()` method.
1st method:

```
SELECT id, json_array_elements_text(json_column)
FROM Table
```

2nd method:

```
SELECT id, json_index.json_column
FROM Table T
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements_text(json_column) AS json_index(json_column) ON true
```

I found both methods give the same output, but **can we use them interchangeably?**

.

Comment: The two queries are not equivalent. The first one will not return rows where the array is empty. It's essentially the same as `select t.id, a.* from t CROSS JOIN json_array_elements_text(json_column) as a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two queries happen to produce the same result. The query with the `LATERAL` join is the explicit (and, in my opinion, better) way to do it.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/xfunc-sql.html#id-1.8.3.8.16.2) describes the first case:

> Functions returning sets can also be called in the select list of a query. For each row that the query generates by itself, the set-returning function is invoked, and an output row is generated for each element of the function's result set.
>
> [...]
>
> PostgreSQL's behavior for a set-returning function in a query's select list is almost exactly the same as if the set-returning function had been written in a `LATERAL FROM`-clause item instead.

The documentation then goes on to describe the subtle differences, but they shouldn't matter in your case.